# How do I update a column in mysql with a python list?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

So I have been looking around a lot. I wouldn't ask the question had any of the answers on SO helped me.

Basically, I have a python list that I want to update my mysql column with. I can't seem to find the right query for it. I am using mysql.connector library to connect to a database.

`fourth_query = 'UPDATE trendsincities SET trends = (%s) cursor.executemany(fourth_query, tuple(trends))`

Where trends is a list that contains strings seperated by commas.

To this, I get an error saying -  ***Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement***

Need help on this. Linking this to a solved question would also be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is `trendsincities` a `VARCHAR` field and you are trying to save a comma-separated-string into it? If so, then you would want something like this:

```
trends = ["best", "city", "new"]
trends_as_csv_string = ",".join(trends)
sql = "UPDATE trendsincities SET trends=%s"
cursor.execute(sql, trends_as_csv_string)
```

However I'm a bit suspicious of this. I think you probably want an `INSERT` if it's a new item? Or, if it's an `UPDATE`, you probably want to use a `WHERE` clause such as:

```
"UPDATE trendsincities SET trends='best,city,new' WHERE city='New York'"
```

Otherwise, each successive update will overwrite the previous.

But if you want to insert each trend you would use this pattern:

```
trends = ["best", "city", "new"]
for trend in trends:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO trendsincities (trend) VALUES (%s)', trend)
```

And then at the end of your sql statement(s) you'll want to issue a `connection.commit()` depending on if you have `autocommit` turned on or not.

Hopefully one of the above approaches will help.

Comment: Thanks David. So running the above returns ValueError: Could not process parameters. The column trends is of data type TEXT. It contains trends of cities. Each trend is seperated by a space. What I wish to do is to retrieve the data of the column, tweak it, and push it back to the database.

Comment: @DeveshDatwani can you please update you question with the schema then?

Comment: Hey, so I worked it around by looping the insert statement for each item in the list of trend with a WHERE clause (linking them to their cities in the same order). I was trying to figure out a way to not do that, but I couldn't find a solution to that. Thanks a lot for being patient and kind. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, was:

```
row = 0
for i in range(0, len(values)):
        row +=1
        val = values[i]
        sql = f"UPDATE teste SET percent = {val} WHERE id = {row}"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        connection.commit()
```

Obs: I'm using mysql.connector to establish a connection with MySQL.